# app.bat to build angular flask application don't work

Tags: angular, flask

my problem is that the execution of this .bat file stops directly after ng build and the copies of the files in static and template are not made.

REM Build Angular app
cd C:\Users\inese\OneDrive\Bureau\stage\app\projetstage
ng build

REM Copy Angular build files to Flask static folder
xcopy  dist* C:\Users\inese\OneDrive\Bureau\stage\app\static\

REM Copy index.html to Flask templates folder
xcopy dist\index.html C:\Users\inese\OneDrive\Bureau\stage\app\template\

REM Build Flask app
cd C:\Users\inese\OneDrive\Bureau\stage\app

REM Run Flask app
python app.py